# item loader skip values scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using item loader with scrapy from multiple page, the item loader returns empty dictionaries for some pages though when i use same rules to parse only these pages it returns the values, anyone could know why?

spider code:

```
class AllDataSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'all_data'  # spider name
    allowed_domains = ['amazon.com']

    # write the start url
    start_urls = ["https://www.amazon.com/s? bbn=2619533011&rh=n%3A2619533011%2Cp_n_availability%3A2661601011&ie=UTF8&qid =1541604856&ref=lp_2619533011_nr_p_n_availability_1"]

    custom_settings = {'FEED_URI': 'pets_.csv'}  # write csv file name

    def parse(self, response):
        '''
        function parses item information from category page
        '''

        self.category = response.xpath('//span[contains(@class, "nav-a- 
                                       content")]//text()').extract_first()

        urls = response.xpath('//*[@data-asin]//@data-asin').extract()

        for url in urls:
            base = f"https://www.amazon.com/dp/{url}"
            yield scrapy.Request(base, callback=self.parse_item)

        next_page = response.xpath('//* 
                                  [text()="Next"]//@href').extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page), 
                                 dont_filter=True)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        loader = AmazonDataLoader(selector=response)
        loader.add_xpath("Availability", '//div[contains(@id, 
                         "availability")]//span//text()')
        loader.add_xpath("NAME", '//h1[@id="title"]//text()')
        loader.add_xpath("ASIN", '//*[@data-asin]//@data-asin')
        loader.add_xpath("REVIEWS", '//span[contains(@id, 
                          "Review")]//text()')
        rank_check = response.xpath('//*[@id="SalesRank"]//text()')
        if len(rank_check) > 0:
            loader.add_xpath("RANKING", '//*[@id="SalesRank"]//text()')

        else:
            loader.add_xpath("RANKING", '//span//span[contains(text(), "#")] 
                             [1]//text()')

        loader.add_value("CATEGORY", self.category)

        return loader.load_item()
```

for some pages it returns all values, for some pages it returns just the category, and for other "that follow same rules when parsing them only" it returns nothing, it also close the spider before finishing and without errors

```
 DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0009X29WK>
{'ASIN': 'B0009X29WK',
 'Availability': 'In Stock.',
 'NAME': " Dr. Elsey's Cat Ultra Premium Clumping Cat Litter, 40 pound bag ( "
         'Pack May Vary ) ',
 'RANKING': '#1',
 'REVIEWS': '13,612'}
2019-01-21 21:13:07 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01N9KSITZ> (referer: https://www.amazon.com/s?i=pets&bbn=2619533011&rh=n%3A2619533011%2Cp_n_availability%3A2661601011&lo=grid&page=2&ie=UTF8&qid=1548097190&ref=sr_pg_1)
2019-01-21 21:13:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01N9KSITZ>
{}
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question? What results are you getting and what results are you expecting to get?

Comment: i was expecting to get values of fields from every product in every page, but for some products i just get empty dictionary, though when i try to scrap **only** one page with the same xpaths i get the values with out any problems.

Comment: Have you double checked the elements on those particular pages?  Theres a decent chance something is different or an add or something along those lines is changing the layout..